# Is the AllowHtml attribute secure

Tags: html, security, model, asp.net-mvc-5, request.form

I have a MVC model field that the user enters some html source code into. Currently, I am getting the following error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client

I have had a look at the following resource: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/09/mvc3-granular-request-validation-update.aspx

The resource says to add the `AllowHtml` attribute. I have added this attribute, and the error is now not occuring.

My question is this: Is there any other security features that I should add to my application, or is the `AllowHtml` attribute all that is required? Should I also use the following protection library: http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`AllowHtml` doesn't include any security to prevent malicious scripting. It's just allowing the property to skip this step in the validation process. You should still check that property to make sure it doesn't contain scripting and either sanitize or reject it if it does.

Comment: I am new to this area of coding, What do you recommend for this? I have found the following resource http://wpl.codeplex.com/. Do you recommend this resource?

Comment: I don't know I've never used it. Googling "Html sanitizer c#" brings up a myriad of libraries that could work.